# SwiftUI: Image contentMode center

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

In Swift I can create `UIImageView` with any size, and then just set `contentMode = .center`
And image in it original size will appear in ImageView in center.

How to achieve this with SwiftUI ?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

So I would like to create Image (36 x 36) with rounded corners and with background colour. And set image in center. How to do that ?

This is what I tried:

```
Image("pool_icn")
                .resizable()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(16)
                .frame(width: 36, height: 36, alignment: .center)
        }
```

And the result is:

[image]

So image resized as well, while I want it to keep original size.

Is that possible with Image ?
Or should I wrap image in container ?

Comment: Is the `pool_icn` just the black lines on a transparent background? Is there any padding on the `pool_icn` image? And also... what shape is it? Is it square?

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, back lines on transparent background. No paddings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I put this together which sort of replicates what you want. I used the `stethoscope` system image but I'm sure you should be able to update it to specifically what you need...

```
struct ContentView: View {
  let imageSize: Double = 24
  let circleSize: Double = 36
  
  var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "stethoscope")
      .resizable()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
      .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
      .frame(width: circleSize, height: circleSize)
      .background(Color.blue)
      .clipShape(Circle())
  }
}
```

I added in the `imageSize` and `circleSize` just to play around with them a bit.

The output looks about right...

[image]

You will only need the `Image` part. I just added the view to show that it's not using anything else.

### A bit more playing

I created an extension on `Image` to `iconify` it...

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Image(systemName: "stethoscope")
        .iconified(imageSize: 30, surroundSize: 50, color: .red)
      
      Image(systemName: "car")
        .iconified(imageSize: 100, surroundSize: 150, color: .green)
      
      Image(systemName: "lungs")
        .iconified(imageSize: 20, surroundSize: 36, color: .blue)
      
      Image(systemName: "keyboard.onehanded.right")
        .iconified(imageSize: 40, surroundSize: 60, color: .orange)
    }
  }
}

extension Image {
  func iconified(imageSize: Double, surroundSize: Double, color: Color) -> some View {
    self
      .resizable()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
      .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
      .frame(width: surroundSize, height: surroundSize)
      .background(color)
      .clipShape(Circle())
  }
}
```

This works nicely...

[image]

### Stop resizing the image

If you want the size of the image to stay at whatever it should be then you can do like this...

```
extension Image {
  func iconified(surroundSize: Double, color: Color) -> some View {
    self
      .frame(width: surroundSize, height: surroundSize)
      .background(color)
      .clipShape(Circle())
  }
}
```

And that will always keep the image in the centre with the size it has straight from the file. This looks like...

[image]

Comment: I made some changes to improve it.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me as expected.
Is it possible to avoid knowing image size ?
Let's say I want to have 100x100 ImageView and I don't want to care about image size as it can be dynamic. Just want to set image in center with it original size.

Comment: @Jim the `imageSize` is not the size of the image in the file but the size that you want the image to be inside the circle. i.e. if you put `imageSize` of 5 then you would have a circle with a really tiny image inside it. If you set `imageSize` of 36 then you would have an image the same size as the circle.

Comment: @Jim ... oh I think I understand... I'll have a play.

Comment: If you want it just to be whatever the size of the image is then you don't know that it will fit in the size of the circle. To do that just remove the `resizable` the `aspectRatio` and the first `frame`.

Comment: Thanks man. I feel like you spent too much time on me ) I really appreciate for you help. Thank you

Comment: @Jim no worries. I enjoy helping out as I learn a lot myself from doing it so it’s a win win. 